# array indexing with pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

the program is not printing the original array though the copy array works perfectly...........can someone please also explain it to me how the while loop is working here( i am new to pointers )......

```
// Copy an array in C++ using pointers

#include<iostream.h>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    char name[] = {'S','P','A','R','T','A','N'};
    char copy[7];
    char *p1, *p2;
    p1 = name;
    p2 = copy;
    while(*p1) *p2++ = *p1++;
    *p2 = 0;
    cout<<"Here is the original name array:\n";
    p1 = name;
    cout<<name<<"\n";
    while(*p1) cout<< *p1++ <<" ";
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Here is the copy:\n";
    p1 = copy;
    while(*p1) cout<< *p1++ <<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten about **null terminators**.

Comment: Aside from the main issue, `<iostream.h>` is an old, deprecated header of classic IOStreams. You should use the modern, standard C++ header `<iostream>` instead.

Comment: @0x499602D2 i was using turbo C while making this prog thats why i had to use iostream.h....for some reason iostream was showing error.

Comment: @sky3287944 _'i was using turbo C '_ **Don't do this!!** Welcome to the 21st century!

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth......please elaborate......i dont have much experience in program.....and i am not understanding what are u trying to say.....

Comment: @sky3287944 To elaborate: `char name[] = {'S','P','A','R','T','A','N'};` should be `char name[] = {'S','P','A','R','T','A','N', /* >> */ '\0' /* << */ };`!!

Comment: You should just use `const char name[] =  "SPARTAN"` and let the compiler do it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is OK to initialize a `char` array the way you are doing it.

But you cannot refer to it as a null-terminated string of characters after that (because the last character is **not** 0). So you cannot pass it to any function that assumes it **is** a null-terminated string of characters.

Function `cout<<` (`operator<<` of the `iostream` class) just happens to be one of those functions.

In addition to that, you cannot loop the array until reaching a 0 character (using `while(*p1)`) because you'll be reading memory passed the end of the array, thus likely performing a memory-access violation.

You can solve both problems by changing:

```
char name[] = {'S','P','A','R','T','A','N'};
```

To:

```
char name[] = "SPARTAN";
```

The compiler will essentially refer to it as:

```
char name[] = {'S','P','A','R','T','A','N','\0'};
```

And there you have a null-terminated string.

Note: '\0' is equivalent to 0, and is also referred to as "null character".